# Is this the correct approach to find acceleration of the wedge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

Consider a block sliding without friction on a wedge as in the following picture:

[image]

Given the height of the block of mass $m$ as a function $h(t)$ of time $t$ with initial height $h(0) = h_0$, is the following method to determine the acceleration of wedge $M$ correct?

Using conservation of energy, the initial potential energy of the block is equal to the final kinetic energy plus potential energy after a time $t$:
$$mgh_0=\frac{1}{2}m(v_1\cos(30^\circ)-v_2)^2+\frac{1}{2}M(v_2)^2+\frac{1}{2}m(v_1\sin(30^\circ))^2 +mgh(t),\tag{1}$$
where $v_1$ is the velocity of the block in frame of the wedge and $v_2$ is the velocity of the wedge w.r.t ground.
Using conservation of momentum in the frame where the ground is at rest, we also have
$$m(v_1\cos(30^\circ)-v_2)=Mv_2\tag{2}.$$

The second equation looks perfectly fine to me as it just momentum conservation. However, the first equation might be incorrect. I applied this technique to solve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG2ra.jpg) problem, which asks for the acceleration of the wedge if the block's height varies as $h(t) = 1.5\ \mathrm{m} + 1.5\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2} t^2$. I solved for $v_2(t)$ from the two equations and then differentiated it to get the final result. The answer I get using this technique (putting $M=m=1$ as the result is independent of mass) is $3 \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$. However, the correct result should have been $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$. I'm certain that there is no trivial calculation error. I've checked it several times.

So, why is equation (1) not applicable in this case?

Comment: Here is a duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277412/104696

Comment: @Farcher That one doesn't really help. I still don't see the error in my method.

Comment: As I understand the site "homework" policy, "Check my work" questions are off topic. The chatrooms are a better place to ask such questions - as you have done.

Comment: @sammygerbil I see a big difference between a typical check-my-work question that goes "is this answer right?" and this question, which has identified *where* in the reasoning process the error has occurred but not *why* the asker's reasoning is mistaken. We can discuss further in [chat] or on [meta] if you like.

Comment: @rob Yes, let us discuss in the [Physics Meta chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36795063#36795063).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I cannot comment (min 50 reputation) I will write it as the answer,
All the equations framed for conservation of energy, momentum were correct.
The point where you were wrong was that you assumed the result is independent of mass.
In fact the particular acceleration of block $m$ height was caused only for that set of masses.
What I am trying to say is the question states that the acceleration of m is $\rm3\ m/s^2$. As you took $m=M=1$, for this set of masses the acceleration will not be $\rm3\  m/s^2$.

Equations one and two are correct, and would have given correct answer if you knew the masses of blocks

Comment: Where does the question state that the acceleration of block is $3 m/s^2$ ? It doesn't.

Comment: Differentiate h(t) twice for acceleration. Or the given eqn is of form x-x0 = ut +(0.5)at^2(Displacement in uniform accelerated motion)

Comment: Ok, I see! In that case are my two equations sufficient to find $dv_2/dt$ without putting any values for $m$ and $M$. I think there are too many variables. Will they all get eliminated?

Comment: No, without putting values of m & M, the equation 1 & 2 are not sufficient.

Comment: If those two equations are not sufficient then what other equation do we need in addition to them? (I like your method of solution using forces/acceleration but I wan't to do it using the energy approach).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics.SE. We try to answer conceptual questions without becoming a homework help service; I've edited out your photograph of a "complete solution."

Comment: @blue Energy conservation and momentum conservation will give the same result. Differentiating twice equation 1 for one more relation.(note: rate of change of acceleration will be zero for both) Also try rewriting equation one with v of mass m in form of V(x) and V(y) and use constraints relation.