# Relative acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

If the accelerations of two objects are such their one of their components are directed opposite to each other , while the other components are directed in the same direction , then why is relative acceleration measured only along the components that are directed in opposite directions? Think about the acceleration of a block that moves on a frictionless wedge placed on a frictionless horizontal surface with respect to the acceleration of the wedge

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzHsH.png)]

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Please can you explain what your first sentence means in relation to the diagram. (Note that the problem of a block sliding on a wedge has be discussed in several answers on this site. See related questions to the right, or make a search, to see if any of these already answer your question.)

Comment: I have a suspicion that you've bumped into a rather specific interpretation intended only for this exercise. And that the question should be re-worded to ask explicitly about the horizontal component of relative acceleration.

Comment: @dmckee: seconded.

Comment: Possibly related to [Free body diagram of block on accelerating wedge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277412)

Comment: @dmckee in the question it was only given that the block slides over the wedge and all surfaces are smooth.

Comment: @sammygerbil What I mean to say is , the acceleration of the wedge is directed horizontally towards the left which can be resolved into two components , one along the incline and one parallel to the incline , also the weight of the block is directed vertically downwards which can similarly be resolved in the same way. Then why do we measure the relative acceleration only along the components parallel to the incline ?

Comment: That is because the block and wedge do not lose contact along the inclined face. ... Imagine the incline turned so that it becomes horizontal like a table. Then the only motion between the block and wedge is horizontal. The block does not lift vertically off the table, neither does it fall down through the table. However, in this frame of reference, the wedge (table) and block could accelerate together up or down (imagine the table is in a lift), but they have the same acceleration vertically, there is no relative acceleration vertically, only horizontally.