# Object falls off an inclined plane, what's the acceleration of the plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

The problem statement is as following: "We have an object with mass m falling down, with friction, on the bigger object with mass M and tilted with the angle alpha. If the bigger object is moving horizontally without friction what is the absolute value of it's acceleration?

Numerical values:
m = 5kg

M = 8 kg

alpha = pi/4

miu(friction  coefficient) = 0.2

correct answer a = 2 m/s^2.

And the drawing is the following:

[image]

Say I represent all the forces that are happening to the little object m and put them on and X,Y axis representative to the bigger object why can't I just say that little object m it's applying a Force equal to all the little object's forces represented on the x,y axis based on the bigger object and just say that the bigger object acceleration is just the sum of all those forces represented times M?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277412/free-body-diagram-of-block-on-accelerating-wedge

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am confused by what you are trying to say in the last paragraph. What you want to do is free body diagram both objects. (the ramp and block)

[image]

Your block should look something like this. (ignore the 30 degrees should be 45 or pi/4 obviously)

Then figure out the diagram for the ramp.

Now you do F=ma in the x and Y direction. I would not turn my axis since the ramp has to be considered as well. For the angles of forces on the block in this case they're all 45 degrees, but if the angle of the ramp were 30 instead you would need to draw right triangles to figure out if sin or cos would be used.

Then solve for the acceleration of the heavier mass in the x-direction

Answer (score 0):

$$mg \sin \alpha- n mg \cos \alpha=ma$$
or, $$g \sin \alpha -n g \cos \alpha = a$$
Acceleration  $a$  depends on friction coefficient  $n$  and angle of inclination  $\alpha$  of the plane.

If  $x= 90°$, then  $a= g$.