# Can it be proven mathematically that the work done by normal force on the complete system of "curved" inclined plane and block is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

Using simple relative motion and Newton's laws of motion, I could prove that the work done by the normal force on a (unmounted straight inclined wedge + block) as a whole system is zero. Similarly, can it be proven mathematically that as the block slides down an unmounted curved inclined plane, the work done by the normal force on the whole system from the ground frame is zero? (The wedge is free to move on the horizontal surface and all surfaces are frictionless.)

[image]

Comment: Which normal force are you asking about?

Comment: @Dale The normal force between the two bodies, acting during the block moves down the wedge.

Comment: You don't have to prove anything.  The normal force is always perpendicular to the surfaces in contact, here, and the direction of motion is always *parallel* to the surfaces in contact, so the normal force does no work in this situation. (Well, provided that the wedge doesn't move.)

Comment: The curved inclined surface can be seen as the limit of a broken line. There're no essential differences. for mathematical rigor, all you need to do is figuring out the slope at each point on the curve.

Comment: @march The wedge isn't fixed

Comment: An internal force can never do work on the system its internal to.

Comment: @BowlOfRed that's a misconception you have.

Comment: Related [Free body diagram of block on accelerating wedge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277412/free-body-diagram-of-block-on-accelerating-wedge/277616#277616) and think about which (component of a ) forces do work to produce horizontal motion.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Think of a bomb (the system), with no external forces acting, exploding.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. Please edit the question to identify the intended normal force in the question. All clarifications should always be placed in the question itself, not left to comments

Comment: @Dale please apply for your suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

---

Similarly, can it be proven mathematically that as the block slides down an unmounted curved inclined plane, the work done by the normal force on the whole system from the ground frame is zero?

---

**Yes offcourse, now I am providing you a brief solution.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**If you want to find out complete work by normal on m and M , I am providing you expression for normal force , find work by integration.**
[image]

**I hope it's clear to you, if not ask in comment**.