# Block and unfixed incline system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

if there is a block on top of an unfixed inline. and if the system is released from rest what is the acceleration of the block and the incline? can someone draw fbd and show? the difficulty in this problem is that you can't figure out the normal force and stuff like that. This is not an a= homework question, I'm genuinely curious about how to draw the fbd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free body diagram of block on accelerating wedge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277412/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the figure attached below helps you...[image]

The observer I have taken shown in fig. is in non-inertial frame of reference. So an additional force pseudo force comes into play.
You can approach the problem through inertial frame also. The result will be the same. But the calculations get lot simpler in non-inertial frame.
[image]

The accelerations of the block are calculated in the above image.(a2 : acc. of block. a1: acc. of wedge).